# Print multipage line drawing in a browser without scalling

Tags: javascript, svg, printing

I want to print a multipage line drawing in a browser without scaling so it can be assembled.  One inch needs to be one inch.  Alignment marks and horz/vert page number would be a plus.

I have played around with SVG to accomplish this and failed.  I have also created a [pdf](https://www.eskimo.com/~gap/Square.pdf) of a 12" by 12" box with that looks like what I want.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lifeofgary/dnx5s6h1) of my attempts.  It prints but not at scale and only prints on 1 page.  Here is the javascript.

```
        printSVG = function() {
          alert("Print")
          var popUpAndPrint = function() {

            var printWindow = window.open('', 'PrintMap');
            var toPrint = $('#toPrint')

            printWindow.document.writeln(toPrint.html())
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
            printWindow.close();
          };
          setTimeout(popUpAndPrint, 500);
        };
```

and the SVG

```
<svg width="12in" height="12in">
  <polyline points="
       0,0 
       1200,1200
       " style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;" />
  <polyline points="
       1200,0 
       0,1200
       " style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:1" />
  <polyline points="
       0,0
       1200,0 
       1200,1200
       0,1200
       0,0
       " style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it (in Chrome) to perfectly obey the measurements of 12in, but I came close when I told it to use larger dimensions: https://jsfiddle.net/dnx5s6h1/16/

Using CSS (inside of the copied DIV), I told the browser to expect that the page is a regular 8.5in x 11in, and its content is 20 inches. Then, it finally obeyed and printed on multiple pages.

```
<style>
  @media only print
  {
    html, body
    {
      width: 8in;
      height: 10in;
      margin: .5in;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Feel free to add margins to you SVG object to get it to print at the bottom of your page.

Comment: Thanks Nate.  I appreciate you responding.  Sorry for the slow response.  I did not get an email notification someone had answered.

Comment: I added your css and added  <svg width="20in" height="20in">.  When I try https://jsfiddle.net/lifeofgary/dnx5s6h1/ it still prints one page.  I am using Chrome Version 54.0.2840.59 (64-bit) and print to pdf for testing.

Comment: @Gary Hey Gary, I'm sorry. I haven't logged in to SO for a week now. The problem is that the Javascript opens a new window and then copies elements into that window. In your link, the CSS is not being copied. That's why in my link (the /16/ link), the CSS is inline of the HTML being copied. Give that a try?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a good way to print SVG in a browser.  Pdf is supported better so I will try [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).